# Implement the functionality of the wc and head controls

Tags: linux, unix, wc, unix-head, symbolicc++

I need help to solve these requirements: Implement the functionality of the wc and head controls.
The wc command will need to use and recognize the -w and -c options.
The head command will need to use and recognize the -c and -n options.
The functionality of the 2 commands in the C / C ++ application will have to be identical to the functionality of the bash wc and head commands (including using the 2 options or generating error messages).
It is not accepted to use the system / exec / execute functions to solve it.

Comment: On Linux, `wc` is part of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) whose source code is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). You are allowed to download the source code, study it, and improve it

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question (for example, some C code with a `main`) and explain in more than one paragraph the relation between [wc(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html) and SymbolicC++. I see no relation between these. Notice that **Stack-Overflow is not a do-my-homework website**